# How to select field from json column from Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to do a very simple query in Postgres 13.   It seems like this should work from reading the documentation, but I keep getting an error saying:

> Error executing SELECT statement. ERROR: column "bar" does not exist
> Position: 8

My Table and data looks like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE thing.foo (
  bar json null
);

INSERT INTO thing.foo (bar) VALUES ('{"handle":123}');

SELECT bar->handle from thing.foo;
```

I've also tried other variants like

`SELECT bar->>'handle' from thing.foo;`,

but Postgres seems certain that the column doesn't exist.  Doing a vanilla select on the top level column *does* work:

`SELECT bar from thing.foo;`

What is the correct way of selecting this field?

Comment: `select bar ->> 'handle'` [works just fine](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b8c0a14886c8cdfd60db14e977229b66)

Comment: You are correct, it turned out to be a problem with my SQL client, not Postgres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little more digging, this isn't a Postgres issue, but a [Database Navigator](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1800-database-navigator) issue for IntelliJ.  What looks like direct SQL queries turned out to be incorrectly rewritten by the IDE's.   This is what the error looks like from IntelliJ:

[image: Sample of the error]

I looked through the Packet Capture with Wireshark and noticed it was issuing a different query than what I requested:

[image: Actual wire bytes]

Some how the query is being mangled between the time I give the query to Database Navigator, and when it gets to the network.